Elastic Search Watcher parsing exception
I am trying to create a elasticsearch watcher which will get some aggregation in last 20 mins with the following conditions:

type is equal to fax
Plan is equal to plan_a
And the aggregations are:
automated - Where the keyword is "System"
total - Count all
rate - automated/total
And the condition is automation rate is less than 20%

I have the following code
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "cron": "0 */5 11-23 ? * MON-FRI"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "servicecase"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": "now-20m",
                    "lt": "now"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_cases": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "type.keyword": "FAX"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "plan.keyword": "plan_a"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "automated_count": {
                    "term": {
                      "outcome.completedBy.keyword": "System"
                    }
                  },
                  "total_count": {
                    "value_count": {
                      "field": "_index"
                    }
                  },
                  "automation_rate": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                      "buckets_path": {
                        "automated": "automated_count>automated_count_value",
                        "total": "total_count"
                      },
                      "script": "(params.automated / params.total) * 100"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.aggregations.filtered_cases.automation_rate.value": {
        "gte": 20
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    ...
  }
}

But I keep getting the following error
"
        root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
            "line": 1,
            "col": 224
          }
        ],

Could anyone help with this issue?
I am expecting the elasticsearch watcher should run with out any error

There are a couple of errors in watcher aggs part.

The syntax of multiple filter aggregation is wrong. Note: The syntax is different from other aggs.
There is no term aggregation but terms aggregation.
You can use include in terms aggregation to filter the value. Note: the term query is not work like terms aggregation

Here is a working example for you.
GET /shakespeare/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-20m",
            "lt": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_cases": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "first_filter": { "term": { "type.keyword": "FAX" } },
          "second_filter": { "term": { "plan.keyword": "plan_a" } }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "automated_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "outcome.completedBy.keyword",
            "include": "System"
          }
        },
        "total_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "_index"
          }
        },
        "automation_rate": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "automated": "automated_count>automated_count_value",
              "total": "total_count"
            },
            "script": "(params.automated / params.total) * 100"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Note: you can use simulate watcher with _execute API call.
